# Payment problems when adding Subscription with Individual products on Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, payment, woocommerce, payment-processing

I noticed that when buying individual products conflict with subscription products when adding to cart.

By adding a subscription and individual product together, the cart automatically removes the subscription product and states that "A subscription has been removed from your cart. Due to payment gateway restrictions, products and subscriptions can not be purchased at the same time."

Is there any other way around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been in touch with WooCommerce about this myself and that say this issue will be addressed in version 2 of the Subscriptions extension which should be out later this year.

I doubt there will be an easy workaround in the meantime.

Comment: Sorry, don't have the link now, but the latest ETA on their website as of a few days ago said Summer 2014... I'm also waiting.